# How to change the NatTable column AutoSize drag icon

Tags: java, nattable

I want to change the NatTable drag icon which is shown when the cursor is in between two columns.

Here's the default icon:

[image: Default icon]

I need to change it to a custom icon like this:

[image: I want to change default icon to the custom one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement and register a custom ColumnResizeCursorAction. Have a look at the default implementation and how it is registered to see what needs to be done.